# Syntax for echoing a class property in a magic quote string

Tags: php

I want to echo the value of a property using magic quotes.

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->foo = 123;
echo "foo: ${obj->foo}";
```

This fails with the following error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in
>   /foobar/test.php on line 3

I know I could write something like this:

```
echo "foo: ".$obj->foo;
```

But shouldn't the curly brackets work in this case too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yours is almost right:

```
echo "foo: {$obj->foo}";
```

[The php reference for complex string syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) says:

> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string
>   representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the
>   expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and
>   then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will
>   only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {.

---

I should have also mentioned this at the time I answered, but the brackets aren't actually needed for this expression.

```
echo "foo: $obj->foo";
```

should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the $ sign my friend.

```
<?php
    $obj = new stdClass;
    $obj->foo = 123;
    echo "foo: {$obj->foo}";
```